# Clase Friends en c++

Tags: c++, lista, class

estoy haciendo una práctica para la universidad y es la primera vez que trabajamos con la etiqueta class friends. Cuento con 3 clases:

```
#ifndef NODO_H
#define NODO_H

template<class T>
class Nodo {
public:
T dato;
Nodo *sig;
Nodo(const T &aDato, Nodo *aSig = 0):dato(aDato), sig(aSig) {}
};

#endif /* NODO_H */


#ifndef ITERADOR_H
#define ITERADOR_H
#include "Nodo.h"
#include "ListaEnlazada.h"

template<class T>
class Iterador {
Nodo<T> *nodo;
friend class ListaEnlazada<T>;//<---aqui esta el error
public:
Iterador(Nodo<T> *aNodo) : nodo(aNodo) {}
bool fin() { return nodo == 0; }
void siguiente() {
nodo = nodo->sig;
}
T &dato() { return nodo->dato; }
};

#endif /* ITERADOR_H */

#ifndef LISTAENLAZADA_H
#define LISTAENLAZADA_H
#include "Nodo.h"
#include "Iterador.h"
template<class T>
class ListaEnlazada {
Nodo<T> *cabecera, *cola;
int tam=0;
public:
ListaEnlazada() : cabecera(0), cola(0) {}
//~ListaEnlazada(); Hay que hacer estoooo
//ListaEnlazada(const ListaEnlazada &l);
//ListaEnlazada &operator=(ListaEnlazada &l);
Iterador<T> iterador() { return Iterador<T>(cabecera); }
void insertarInicio(T &dato);
void insertarFinal(T &dato);
//oid insertar(Iterador<T> &i, T &dato);
//void borrarInicio();
//void borrarFinal();
//void borrar(Iterador<T> &i);
//T &inicio();
//T &final();
int dimeTam(){return tam;}
};

template<class T>
T ListaEnlazada<T>::leer(int n) {
    Nodo<T> *nodo = cabecera;
    while (n-- > 0 && nodo != 0) {
        nodo = nodo->sig;
    }
    if (nodo != 0)
        return nodo->dato;
    return 0;
}
```

El trabajo consiste en crer una lista enlazada desde 0, por lo que he hecho sus primeros metodos que sería los de insertar cosa que me funcionaba bien. Ahora quería leer un dato de la lista por lo que necesitaba un iterador(es la primera vez que trabajo con ellos). La profesora nos ha dado el código del Iterador pero al introducirlo me sale un error, no me reconococe la clase ListaEnlazada como una plantilla de clase aunque tiene puesto su Template. LLevo ya tiempo mirandolo sin encontrar lógica alguna.

Comment: "*nos ha dado el código del Iterador pero al introducirlo me sale un error*" ¿Qué error? ¿Dónde? ¿Al compilar o al ejecutar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tienes una interdependencia entre las cabeceras:

Iterador.h

```
#include "ListaEnlazada.h"
```

ListaEnlazada.h

```
#include "Iterador.h"
```

Esto no te va a funcionar jamás en C++.

La directiva `#include` se reemplaza por el contenido del archivo enlazado. Es decir:

```
#ifndef LISTAENLAZADA_H
#define LISTAENLAZADA_H
#include "Iterador.h"
template<class T>
class ListaEnlazada {
  // ...
};
#endif // LISTAENLAZADA_H
```

Se convierte en

```
#ifndef LISTAENLAZADA_H
#define LISTAENLAZADA_H

#ifndef ITERADOR_H
#define ITERADOR_H
#include "ListaEnlazada.h"

template<class T>
class Iterador {
  friend class ListaEnlazada<T>;
  // ...
};
#endif // ITERADOR_H

template<class T>
class ListaEnlazada {
  // ...
};
#endif // LISTAENLAZADA_H
```

Vaya otro include ... seguimos reemplazando

```
#ifndef LISTAENLAZADA_H
#define LISTAENLAZADA_H

#ifndef ITERADOR_H
#define ITERADOR_H

#ifndef LISTAENLAZADA_H
#endif // LISTAENLAZADA_H

template<class T>
class Iterador {
  friend class ListaEnlazada<T>;
  // ...
};
#endif // ITERADOR_H

template<class T>
class ListaEnlazada {
  // ...
};
#endif // LISTAENLAZADA_H
```

En esta ocasión, el include se reemplaza por ... nada. Como la cabecera está protegida por un `#ifdef`, y el símbolo `LISTA_ENLAZADA_H` ya está definido, el código protegido por la guarda simplemente será ignorado.

Así las cosas, si te fijas, en el momento de usar `friend`, aún no se ha declarado `ListaEnlazada` y ese es justo el error que te está indicando el compilador.

¿La solución? Usar *declaration forward*:

```
#ifndef LISTAENLAZADA_H
#define LISTAENLAZADA_H

// declaration forward
template<class T> class Iterador;

template<class T>
class ListaEnlazada {
  // ...
};

# include "Iterador.h"
// A partir de aqui ya puedes implementar funciones que hagan uso de Iterador<T>
// ...

#endif // LISTAENLAZADA_H
```

Y lo mismo en `Iterador.h`

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias, me gustaría acabar sabiendo tanto como tu jajaja